# PHP | imagejpeg() | from .gif to .jpg | black background?

Tags: php, image-processing, gif

Trying to take a `.gif` and make it a `.jpg` with white background using `imagejpeg()`.

If I do this from a `.jpg` file all is well and good with a white background, but using from a `.gif` creates black background ...

```
$src = imagecreatefromgif($original_file);
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagealphablending($tmp, false);
imagesavealpha($tmp, true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($tmp, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($tmp, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $transparent);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($tmp, $new_file, 80);
```

**TROUBLESOME GIF**

[image]

**CODE IN THE DUPLICATE WORKS**

The duplicate in question is about converting PNGs to JPG. But there is code that that works for converting GIFs to JPG.

Comment: To a JPEG with transparent background? I'm quite sure jpeg does not handle transparent.

Comment: @Andreas You are correct. I mean a white background

Comment: @Andreas That question is about PNG to JPG. The OP even states that he tried the same process with PNG and GIF and got different results.

Comment: How about sharing your troublesome GIF?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added the troublesome GIF

Comment: There is code in the question about Gif -> jpeg.

Comment: @Andreas The code in the other question works for what I am trying to do .. I apologize. Not trying to start a flame war.

Comment: No worries. I'm not angry or upset in any way. I'm just trying to help.